# Parse OAI2/ XML format

Tags: python, api, oai

I have this format to parse:  http://export.arxiv.org/oai2?verb=GetRecord&identifier=oai:arXiv.org:0804.2273&metadataPrefix=arXiv

So I want to get the author's names:

```
import urllib.request
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url_to_fetch)
xml = response.read()

root = ET.fromstring(xml)


for record in root.find(OAI+'ListRecords').findall(OAI+"record"):
    meta = record.find(OAI+'metadata')
    info = meta.find(ARXIV+"arXiv")
    authors = info.findall(ARXIV + 'authors/' + ARXIV + 'author')
    for author in authors:
        forenames = author.find(ARXIV+'forenames').text
        keyname = author.find(ARXIV+'keyname').text
        print(forenames)
        print(keyname)
```

But I get this error:

```
forenames = author.find(ARXIV+'forenames').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

The problem is forenames, if I remove it everything works fine. How can I fix it?

Comment: Should it be author.find(ARXIV + 'author') without the 's'?

Comment: thanks, the error dissapears. However when i try to print authors I get "None"

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  In general, an off-site link is not acceptable, and your posted code fails on an undefined variable.

Comment: In your example author field does not have text, you have to print keyname and/or forenames fields

Comment: Thank you very much, @Nico238 ! this solved the problem. Do you know how is the sintax to get together the keyname and forenames? I have tried:  'authors': [author.find(ARXIV + 'keyname' ARXIV + 'forenames').text for author in authors]. 
Also, where can I learn more about this? I did not find references. Thanks again

Comment: The documentation you&amp;#39;re looking for is the xml parsing lib : https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html . You can try [ ' '.join(author.find(ARXIV+'keyname').text,author.find(ARXIV+'forenames ').text) . Remeberer that text returns the text associated to a node and you find the node with find method on a parent node.

Comment: Thanks @Nico238 I have tried it without sucess and I have now edited and improved my question after reading the reference that you suggest to me

Comment: Have you try without the ARXIV? I don't know what this refers to.